# How to make a persistent CountdownTimer in Android?

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I want make a CountDownTimer and in every tick I want to show the countdown in a Activity.
All the process are going fine in a single Activity but if I close the app the counter reset. I need a way to keep the counter even if the application is closed.
I do not want to use implementations with

> System.currentTimeMillis()

because it changes my counter if the user changes the system clock.

Can anybody help me? Any example code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()). This method returns a value that is unaffected by the system date - therefore the user cannot manipulate it, and unless the phone is rebooted, it's close to ideal for your countdown.

Here's an idea on how to use it:

1. Save the current value to `SharedPreferences` and a flag for that you are currently counting down.
2. Create a `Handler` and use its `postDelayed` method to periodically update the remaining time (a simple subtraction and division). It should be started in `onResume` and stopped in `onPause`.
3. In `onResume` and the `postDelayed` callback, check if the timer is already expired and self-destruct the phone. :)

Comment: can you show some piece of code implementing the same